# single image for all ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Perhaps we use one image for all ldpi, hdpi, mdpi and xdpi where we need to keep the image(in which folder).  This is a bit confusion to me. Can anybody clarify my confusion?

Comment: Check this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources

Answer (score 3):

Just keep it in `res/drawable`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not recommended as the images you use will then not scale well for different device screen sizes. But if you place an image in `res/drawable` this will work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating all of the different folder buckets, `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, etc. Just create one folder, `drawable`, and then put your images in there and when Android searchs for the image and doesn't find the other folders it will default to the `drawable` folder as the only resource. This folder is understood by Android to be equal to the `drawable-mdpi` and will scale the images accordingly.

**EDIT:** Also available is the `res/drawable-nodpi`, This will not scale your image at all and it will retain the same size on all screens.

Comment: res/drawable is assumed to be mdpi (the baseline), and will be scaled. drawable-nodpi will not be scaled at all, and is always the exact same size image.

Comment: @StevenByle so that deserves -1? I said it is similar, not the same. I also stated that I just heard of it and was not familiar with it, and that it was an OPTION. Notice that my first answer is that EXACT same solution as everyone that has upvotes...?

Comment: Correct, you said it was similar, but it isn't similar at all, and that is bad advice to give to a novice dev. Also, none of the answers here are very good, as none of them mention that `drawable == drawable-mdpi`. Mention that an what I have about nodpi and I will upvote your answer.

Comment: @SteveByle Thank you for that since today was the first day that I had heard of `drawable-nodpi` anyways and thought that I would update this answer to provide the option. I also did not know about `drawable == drawable-mdpi`, or at least I did not remember if I have heard it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [How to Support Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support)

> The "default" resources are those that are not tagged with a configuration qualifier. For example, the resources in drawable/ are the default drawable resources. The system assumes that default resources are designed for the baseline screen size and density, which is a normal screen size and a medium density. As such, the system scales default density resources up for high-density screens and down for low-density screens, as appropriate.

So yes, drawable folder is what you are looking for.